# I want to leave blank on a tabular box

Tags: tables

I want to leave more blank on a tabular box for professors's notes.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|p{4cm}|}
    \hline
     $\bullet$ Date du TP : \textit{20/10/2019} \\ $\bullet$ Date de remise : \textit{9/11/2019} \\ $\bullet$ Remarque : \textit{partie Matlab non faite car la conversion du fichier de Matlab 2018a vers le 2014a n'a pas fonctionnée} & Evaluation Finale : \\\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ Notes : \smallbreak $\bullet$ }\\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you post a Minimal Working Example, insted of a code snippet.

Comment: Where exactly would you like to leave some blank space in your table? Probably a sketch of the desired output would help clarify your question.

Comment: @leandriis I want to leave blank on the multicolumn Notes. I'm not allowed to share pics yet to clarify my problem.

Comment: @Hibou: Like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP6we.png

Comment: @leandriis exactly like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add increase the row height of a single table ros you can use `\\[<length of your choice here>]` instead of the regular `\\` to end this specific row.

In the following example, I have also made some other changes to your table. First, I have replaced the `center` environment with the `\centering` command since the former adds some additional white space that might be undesired. I have also replaced the first two `\\` `\newline`. With theis, you get a continuous vertical line at the right side of your table. If you want to keep "Evaluation Finale"  in the same row as "Remarque", you can use the solution presente in the second table, where I have replaced the first tow occurences of `\\` with `& \\`, also in order to make the vertical line continuous.

Instead of the `3cm` and `5cm` in the below examples you can of course use any other length that suits your needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|p{4cm}|}
    \hline
     $\bullet$ Date du TP : \textit{20/10/2019} \newline 
     $\bullet$ Date de remise : \textit{9/11/2019} \newline
     $\bullet$ Remarque : \textit{partie Matlab non faite car la conversion du fichier de Matlab 2018a vers le 2014a n'a pas fonctionnée} 
     & Evaluation Finale : \\\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ Notes : \smallbreak $\bullet$ }\\[3cm]
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|p{4cm}|}
    \hline
     $\bullet$ Date du TP : \textit{20/10/2019} & \\ 
     $\bullet$ Date de remise : \textit{9/11/2019} & \\
     $\bullet$ Remarque : \textit{partie Matlab non faite car la conversion du fichier de Matlab 2018a vers le 2014a n'a pas fonctionnée} 
     & Evaluation Finale : \\\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ Notes : \smallbreak $\bullet$ }\\[5cm]
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```